# Most efficient way to store user profile information

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, database

Okay, so I have my user table ready with columns for all the technical information, such as username, profile picture, password and so on. Now I'm at a situation where I need to add superficial profile information, such as location, age, self-description, website, Facebook account, Twitter account, interests etc. In total, I calculated this would amount to **12** new columns, and since my user table already has 18 columns, I come at a crossroads. Other questions I read about this didn't really give a bottom-line answer of the method that is most efficient.

I need to find out if there is a more efficient way, and **what is the most efficient way to store this kind of information?** The base assumption being that my website would in the future have millions of users, so an option is needed that is able to scale.

I have so far concluded two different options:

**Option 1: Store superficial data in user table, taking the total column count in users table up to 30.**

Or

**Option 2: Store superficial data in separate table, connecting that with Users table.**

Which of these has better ability to scale? Which is more efficient? Is there a third option that is better than these two?

A special extra question also, if anyone has information about this; how do the biggest sites on the internet handle this? Thanks to anyone who participates with an answer, it is hugely appreciated.

My current databse is MySQL with rails mysql2 gem in Rails 4.

Comment: Do you really need it to scale that much ? Or wouldn't it be easier to worry when you actually have those millions of users ? Everyone wants a website that scales to bazillions these days ...  =P

Comment: Well, if there is a way to do that with what I've got, I'll do it. The better the foundation, the easier it is to migrate/transform in the future.

Comment: If you showed us some proposed table designs we could actually comment on the designs. Right now it is a bit vague.   The slowest part of a databasr is normally the disk io so I would go fot multiple tables so I can place them on seperate disks for higher throughput.  However without aome examples I am just guessing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, I would go with the second option. I suppose this would be more efficient because you would retrieve data from `table 1` whenever the user logins and you would use data from `table 2` (superficial data) whenever you change his preferences. You would not have to retrieve all data each time you want to do something. In the bottom line, **I would suggest modelling your data according to your usage scenarios (use cases), creating data entities (eg tables) matching your use case entities**. Then you should take into account the database [normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) principles.

If you are interested on how these issues are handled by the biggest sites in the world, you should know that they do not use relational (SQL) databases. They actually use [NoSQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoSQL) databases, which run on a distributed function. This is a much more complicated scenario than yours. If you want to see related tools, you could start reading about [Cassandra](http://cassandra.apache.org/) and [hadoop](http://hadoop.apache.org/).

Hope I helped!

Comment: Even though my question might have been slightly ambiguous, I think you definitely pointed me to the right direction, so this deserves to be the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you will need to access to these 30 columns of information frequently, you could put all of them into the same table. That's what some widely-used CMS-es do because even though a row is big, it's faster to retrieve one big row than plenty of small rows on various tables (more SQL requests, more searches, more indexes, ...).

Also a good read for your problem is [Database normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization).